# UISearchDisplayController automatically creates a UIPopovercontroller to display content search result ?! How to dismiss it?

Tags: ipad, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using a UISearchDisplayController with a UISearchBar. I put this UISearchBar in my app using IB and I get :

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1985/screenshot20100701at156.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1985/screenshot20100701at156.png)

Fine : when you start taping, the result popovercontroller appears magically (I didn't write anything on my own to make it appear !)

Then, when a row is clicked among the result, I want to dismiss the PopoverController *BUT* at this stage, I never instantiated the UIPopoverController on my side : it looks like if there's an encapsulated behavior in the `UISearchDisplayController` that automatically wraps its `searchContentsController` inside a `UIPopoverController`. That's really great because everything works perfectly without doing anything except that I cannot get the reference to this UIPopoverController to dismiss it :(

**Does anyone know how to get the reference to this "magically" created UIPopoverController ?**
 (this is the proof the iPad is really a "magical" device ;)

I thought there would be a reference to the UIPopoverController from its contentController (through its parent property for instance), but I cannot find any way to get a pointer to it :/

Comment: I also tried to resign the search bar as first responder, but the popover remains visible :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does `[searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];` not work then?

Comment: You know what ? I just thought about trying this but before, I checked if someone answered the question on SO and yes, you're right, it works ! I'm glad to give you the +100 just before the deadline ! :p

Comment: Glad I could help. I hadn't even checked that it worked, but just looked at Apple's Developer Documentation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

None of above solutions worked for me, but I solved it with this:

```
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

This way cursor stays in the field but popover is dismissed when there are no results.

Full code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
        [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some more details on how you have wired up the UISearchDisplayController in IB? It does not do anything special with UIPopoverControllers on the iPad so I assume you have set the searchContentsController to a controller that is a UIPopoverController? If so then you already have the reference you need, though normally you do not need to dismiss this view, it is dismissed for you when you cancel the search.

Comment: the UISearchDisplayController is not wired with anything special : http://bit.ly/bESjTT I've uploaded a very basic XCode project that just isolates the use case at http://bit.ly/aG3qAY It's just the Split view controller project example, with a UISearchDisplayController added. In this project, no UIPopoverController is instantiated :/ The SearchContentController is set to a UIViewController and not to a UIPopoverCOntroller.