# Is UISplitViewController automatically linked to a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to make an iPad version of the app I am developing. The app works really well on iPhones but I'm facing problems on iPads.

Basically, in the iPad version, I add a `UISplitViewController` containing a `UITabBarController` as main controller ( left side of the screen ) whose first view controller contains a `UITableViewController`.

There is a `UISearchBar` to allow the user to filter the table view.

The problem is, on the iPad version, when I use the search bar, an other table view - with filtered content - pops up with an "arrow" pointing at the search bar.

My question is : what is this other table view that appears and how can I disable it ?

**EDIT**

I found this on [this website](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch22.html)

> In a few situations, the framework will automatically create and
>   display a popover for you. One such situation is what happens when a
>   search bar (a UISearchBar) tied to a search display controller
>   (UISearchDisplayController) appears in a toolbar (UIToolbar) on the
>   iPad.

[image]

That's exactly what I'm talking about. How can I disable this popover ?

**EDIT 2**

Just found this topic : [UISearchDisplayController automatically creates a UIPopovercontroller to display content search result ?! How to dismiss it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157590/uisearchdisplaycontroller-automatically-creates-a-uipopovercontroller-to-display)

Problem is : the provided solution doesn't fit my needs. I'd like to be able to search directly through my table view, I just don't want this popover to appear at all.

**EDIT 3**

Solutions founds :

I am not using `UISearchDisplayController` anymore.
Either `UISearchController` or just a selector triggered whenever changes are made on my `UISearchBar`'s text field.

Comment: If iOS 8 is okay for you as a deployment target you can use [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html).